# Adding enum on model shows error on initializing different class object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have added enum on RvDate model as:

```
class RvDate < ApplicationRecord
 enum status: { Available: 0, Not_Available: 1 }

 # Associations
 belongs_to :rv

 # Validations
 validates_presence_of :start_date
end
```

But when I run `Rv.create` on rails console, it shows me the following error:
[image: Error shown on creating new Rv]

I have not used enum on Rv model and I do not need one. Is there anything I have missed here?

Rv model looks like this:

```
class Rv < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :rv_dates, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Schema for rv_dates

```
create_table "rv_dates", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "rv_id"
 t.date     "start_date"
 t.date     "end_date"
 t.boolean  "availability"
 t.float    "price"
 t.text     "notes"
 t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
 t.integer  "status"
 t.index ["rv_id"], name: "index_rv_dates_on_rv_id", using: :btree
end
```

Comment: Can you add the error text as text? Images can be hard to read

Comment: @SimpleLime The error text looks like this: NoMethodError: undefined method `statuses' for #<Class:0x0000000d0e9bf8>

Comment: Why don't you add enum to `Rv` like you did to `RvDate`?

Comment: @TanNguyenNhat Shouldn't it just work fine on adding to RvDate model only?

Comment: Is mentioned above is the full Rv code you have? (if no, post full code of it please) I think it doesn't have any relation to your enum and issues is in another place

Comment: can you share `:rvs` table please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array instead of a hash, the enum will automatically assign the values, and should allow you to use the helper methods:

```
enum status: [
  :available,
  :not_available
]
```

This should allow you to use the helper methods like so:

```
RvDate.statuses => { available: 0, not_available: 1 }
some_rv = RvDate.new
some_rv.status = :available
some_rv.available? => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help. The actual issue was with the migration file. **Rvs** table had a field called **status** which was set to **integer** instead of **string**. Thus, this had caused the error *unable to find the statuses for Rv class object*. Really appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score -1):

Ruby doesn’t have a built-in enum type

Create a constant:

```
STATUSES = { available: 0, not_available: 1 }
```

Access:

`RvDate::STATUSES[:available]`

`RvDate::STATUSES[:not_available]`

Comment: The enum works fine for RvDate. However it is not letting to create new Rv.

Comment: Can you post schema.rb?

Comment: What about your migrations? Can you share them?